# Python Falcon CORS Error with AJAX

Tags: python, ajax, cors, axios, falconframework

I've read multiple SO questions on this error, but none of them seem to be helping me resolve this issue. The Falcon server isn't even printing out the `print` statements of the `on_post` method (`on_get` is working fine for some reason), not sure what's wrong with my `on_post` method.

---

I'm calling a post method from my `localhost:8000` as such:

```
#client side
var ax = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000/api/',
    timeout: 2000,
    headers: {}
});

ax.post('/contacts', {
    firstName: 'Kelly',
    lastName: 'Rowland',
    zipCode: '88293'
}).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data.data);
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log('This is the catch statement');
});
```

---

This is the Falcon server code

```
import falcon
from peewee import *


#declare resources and instantiate it
class ContactsResource(object):
    def on_get(self, req, res):
        res.status = falcon.HTTP_200
        res.body = ('This is me, Falcon, serving a resource HEY ALL!')
        res.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    def on_post(self, req, res):
        res.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        print('hey everyone')
        print(req.context)
        res.status = falcon.HTTP_201
        res.body = ('posted up')

contacts_resource = ContactsResource()

app = falcon.API()

app.add_route('/api/contacts', contacts_resource)
```

I imagine that I'm making a small error in my `on_post` method, but I can't tell what it is. I would've assumed that at least the `print` statements would work but they are not.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a handler for the [CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) the browser sends, right?

The server must respond to the `OPTIONS` with a 200 or 204 and no response body and include the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response headers.

So something like this:

```python
def on_options(self, req, res):
    res.status = falcon.HTTP_200
    res.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    res.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST')
    res.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type')
```

Adjust the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` value to whatever you actually need.

Or you can use the `falcon-cors` package:

```
pip install falcon-cors
```

…then change your existing code to:

```
from falcon_cors import CORS

cors_allow_all = CORS(allow_all_origins=True,
                      allow_all_headers=True,
                      allow_all_methods=True)

app = falcon.API(middleware=[cors.middleware])

#declare resources and instantiate it
class ContactsResource(object):

    cors = cors_allow_all

    def on_get(self, req, res):
        res.status = falcon.HTTP_200
        res.body = ('This is me, Falcon, serving a resource HEY ALL!')
    def on_post(self, req, res):
        print('hey everyone')
        print(req.context)
        res.status = falcon.HTTP_201
        res.body = ('posted up')

contacts_resource = ContactsResource()

app.add_route('/api/contacts', contacts_resource)
```

You may also need to set the `allow_credentials_all_origins=True` option.

Comment: Does the request go from the `OPTIONS` method (`on_options`) straight to the `on_post` method so that it does in fact get to my logic?

Comment: After the browser sends the `OPTIONS` request, if it gets the expected response with the necessary `Access-Control-Allow-*` response headers, then the browser goes ahead and sends the `POST` request from your client code, which when your server gets it causes it to then call your `on_post` method